# Apache2 with mod_perl, it doesn't follow symlinks; How can I fix this?

Tags: apache2, symlink, mod-perl

`mod_perl/apache` doesn't seem able to follow symlinks.

In `httpd.conf` I have:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName cas.devserver.com
        ServerAlias cas.devserver.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@devserver.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/abc/def
        PerlSwitches -I/var/www/cgi-bin
        PerlSendHeader On
        <Location />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                PerlSendHeader On
                PerlHandler Test1::Test
                SetHandler perl-script
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

If `/var/www/cgi-bin/Test1` is a directory containing `Test.pm`, then it works. If it is a symlink to the directory that contains `Test.pm` (`/var/www/cgi-bin/test1/`) then it fails:

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed to resolve handler `Test1::Test':
      Can't locate Test1/Test.pm in @INC
      (@INC contains: /var/www/cgi-bin/ <snip> /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 . /etc/httpd)
      at (eval 9) line 3.\n
```

I've checked permissions and they seem OK.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple obvious question,

Have you tried running your cgi script from the command line with the symlink in place?

Shouldn't you also add to the container?

```
Options +ExecCGI
```

HTH

cheers,

Comment: Thanks Rob.

It worked fine from the command line. The +ExecCGI fixed it.